# What is WooCommerce alternative to WordPressfilter `the_content` for product page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am trying to modify product content (generated by TM Global Extra Product Options plugin) before it is published. I thought i will use the_content filter, byt it doesn't seam to work for products. Any ideas?

Comment: For short description or the full description field for the product?

Comment: probably for full description, but not sure.  I need to edit the plugin's output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the filter **woocommerce_short_description** to modify the content of the short description text of a product.  The long description uses **the_content** filter like normal WordPress post content.

I took a look at the plugin and I can that the hook that it uses to output the fields depends on what option you have selected in **Extra Options placement** setting.

Comment: This might be the correct answer, but unfortunately it doesn't help in my case.  The plugin is probably doing it different way.

Comment: I doubt it, they'd be using the same filters, if you want to overwrite something then you need to execute the filter with a lower priority ( higher number) otherwise your code will be overwritten by their output.  I'll take a look at the plugin.

Comment: What text are you trying to change in the plugin?  What have you added?  I have the plugin.

Comment: There are more things I need to change on it, but the most important part is that I want to add additional values to each item (in my case checkbox).  The idea is to add the data to description separated by `#` and using them on front end (to add specific class to each product, etc) and hiding some of this items based on this data.

Comment: Ok the output of the extra product options depends on which option you have selected in the "Extra Options placement" setting under the "Display" tab.  What have you selected for this configuration?

Comment: Before add to cart button.

Comment: do you know by any chance how to get the description when I have order ID. I am able to get image and name using `wc_get_order_item_meta( $item_id, '_tmcartepo_data', true );` but no description

Comment: Ok looks like if you use the filter "woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button" then you can add extra information after the current extra fields output.  Use the function get_description() or get_short_description() on the product object you create by calling the function wc_get_product( $product_id )

Comment: `woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button` didn't get any data (I tried both  `add_action` and `add_filter`) and the same with the `get_description()` and `get_short_description()`. Anyway, I will probably have to go the jQuery way.

Comment: This is the code I used for testing. `PC` is PHPConsole class `function my_content_second( $content ) {
 PC::tag($content, 'content');

   $product = wc_get_product( 1689 );
   PC::tag($product, 'product-1');

   $desc = $product->get_description();
   PC::tag($desc, 'desc-1');

   $short_desc = $product->get_short_description();
   PC::tag($short_desc, 'short_desc-1');

    // return $content;
    // return 'XXXX';
}

// add_action('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'my_content_second');
add_filter('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'my_content_second');`

Comment: woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button is an action not a filter, you've defined it as both.